# Why string variable must be memory from solidity v5.0?

Tags: solidity, state-variable

May someone explain me why exactly string variable must be memory from solidity v5.0 and what does tha mean?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> why exactly string variable must be memory

That's not true. It would be helpful to know what you are reading that gives that impression.

This compiles:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract StringStorage {

    string[] public str;

    function push(string memory s) public {
        str.push(s);
    }

    function pop() public view returns(string memory s) {
        string storage _s = str[str.length-1]; // not memory
        s = _s;
    }
}
```

I suspect it depends on context. You can only set to `memory` in `public` and `external` function arguments, because storage pointers from outside the contract don't make a lot of sense.

This compiles:

```
function set(uint i, string storage s) internal {
    string storage updateString = str[i];
    updateString = s;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes me a little clearer.

Comment: Thanks for upvoting and accepting my answer.